# What URL should I use to test IBM cognos Mobile, and what are the expected results?

Tags: automated-testing, cognos

I need to test IBM Cognos Mobile functionality and need to have an accurate baseline/reference point.

What URL should I use to test Cognos?  Is it https://server.somthing.com/IBMCognos/M  <-- trailing M?

I'm getting different results in different browsers so I'm not sure what is expected, or if there is some undesired redirection occurring.

Comment: What version? What "different results" were you getting? What are you testing with, or how are you testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27037028&aid=1

> To use the IBM Cognos Mobile WebApp on the other supported devices, open a web browser to the following URL:
>   http:// servername/ibmcognos/m or http:// servername/ibmcognos/m/isapi

(Had to insert a space in the URLs, markdown complained about the "servername" URL. Which is stupid.)